# Setting up factory girl with cucumber and rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, factory-bot

I'm trying to get factory girl setup with rails 3, but I'm getting this error when I `rake cucumber`:

> ```
> james@james-laptop:~/rails-projs/simple-beach-63$ rake cucumber:wip
> (in /home/james/rails-projs/simple-beach-63)
> bundle exec /usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.4/lib:lib"
> ```
>
> "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.9.4/bin/cucumber"
>   --profile wip
>       Using the wip profile...
>       uninitialized constant Factory (NameError)
>       /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-expectations-2.1.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in
>   `const_missing'
>       /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/factory_girl-1.3.3/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb:25
>       /home/james/rails-projs/simple-beach-63/features/support/env.rb:8:in`require'
>       /home/james/rails-projs/simple-beach-63/features/support/env.rb:8

Can you pull and take a look when you get a sec?

I have this in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails'
gem 'factory_girl'
```

I have this in feature/support/env.rb

```
require "factory_girl/step_definitions"
require "factory_girl"
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/factories"
```

and then I define a factory in features/support/factories.rb

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: What happens if you use the factory_girl_rails gem instead?

Answer (score 8):

You should only need these steps.

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end

group :test do
  gem "cucumber-rails"
  gem "factory_girl_rails"
end
```

features/support/factory_girl.rb:

```
require 'factory_girl/step_definitions'
```

spec/factories.rb:

```
# your Factory definitions.
```

Answer (score 3):

Dan,

I've followed your steps but I still cannot use the factory girl step definitions.

When I try :

```
  Given I am not logged in
  And   the following user exists:
    | login  | email               | password   | confirmation |
    | user50 | user50@mydomain.com | secret50   | secret 50    |
 ...
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined step: "the following user exists:" (Cucumber::Undefined exception)

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:
Given /^the following user exists:$/ do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Any ideas on what's missing?

Comment: You need to `require 'factory_girl_rails'` first in features/support/factory_girl.rb as the step definitions are generated from your factories.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're not calling your table correctly.  The line that calls the table from your feature file should look like this:

```
And the following user with <login> and <email> <password> and <confirmation> exists
```

Your step definition should look like:

```
And /^The following user with ([A-za-z0-9\.@:]+) and ([A-za-z0-9\.@:]+) ([A-za-z0-9\.@:]+) and ([A-za-z0-9\.@:]+) exists$/ do |login, email, password, confirmation|
```